# Apply MVC pattern in ES6 for invoking methods

Tags: model-view-controller, ecmascript-6, iife

I am using the Model-View-Controller framework to structure my files for readable, reusable, and refactorable purposes.

My goal is to invoke methods from two seperate classes while working with one class. In practice; I want to access the methods for example in file `Model.js` and `View.js` from `Controller.js`.

Previously in ES5 I've had one file called `app.js` that used the IIFE approach:

```
var View = (function(){

   dump(){
     console.log('Hello World');
   }

 });

var Model = (function(){
  // Code goes here
});

 var Controller = (function(viewCtrl, viewCtrl){

   viewCtrl.dump(); // Invoke method from View

 })(View, Model);
```

As shown above, I would like to do something similar in ES6 too.

```
import View from './View';
import Model from './Model';

class Controller {

   dump(){
      return viewCtrl.dump(); 
   }

   init(){
      console.log('Application has started'); 
      // Make a new object of the class { View, Model }
      let view = new View();
      let model = new Model(); 
   }

}

export default Controller;
```

In my main.js:

```
import Controller from './Controller';

// Make a new object of the class Controller
let controller = new Controller(); 


// Instantiate App
controller.init(); 

console.log(
   controller.dump()
);
```

But doing so in ES6 I get `error: ReferenceError: viewCtrl is not defined` in main.js.

I was thinking perhaps pass `View.js` and `Model.js` as arguments in a constructor inside the `Controller.js` in order to declare them. But I guess it might be a better solution that looks cleaner.

So what I am basically looking for is to apply the MVC pattern using ES6, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the instances of `View` and `Model` to the constructor of `Controller`  is a clean solution since this would fullfill the dependency-injection-pattern. 
This way you get the ability to change the instances from outside which makes the `Controller` testable.

In a situation where  `View` and `Model` where singletons you could export them as instances instead of classes like

View.js:

```
export default new View();
```

Controller.js:

```
import view from "./View";
...
view.dump()
```

Using this way you could spare the work of passing a model and a view to a Controller manually but that would also mean that you loose the ability to test Controller or to change parts of it, like the View. Since this is one of the best advantages of the MVC-pattern, I would not recommend to import singletons. Instead I would recommend to inject `View` and `Model` using a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I didn't understand the last sentence you wrote. What approach do you then recommend? The singletons way, or passing instances of `View` and `Model` to the constructor of `Controller`?

Comment: I would recomment to use the constructor. (I've also updated the text above)

Comment: In fact, I have tryied to use singletons myself because I was too lazy to carry dependencies manually through several function- or constructor-calls, but that way I wasn't able to write unit-tests anymore...